# Flutter: How to make a Form that is longer than one screen

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I want to make a very basic flutter [form](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/validation) with validation. But, I will have more questions than will fit on one screen, so I put my form fields in a [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html), like this:

```
class SurveyView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Iterable<String> questions;

  const SurveyView(this.questions, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SurveyViewState createState() => _SurveyViewState();
}

class _SurveyViewState extends State<SurveyView> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: ListView(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 10),
              children: widget.questions
                      .map((q) => SurveyQuestionView(q))
                      .toList()
                      .cast<Widget>() +
                  [
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Ok!')));
                          } else {
                            ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Text('Some form fields missing')));
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text("Submit")),
                  ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SurveyQuestionView extends StatelessWidget {
  final String question;

  const SurveyQuestionView(this.question, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 0),
      width: double.maxFinite,
      child: Card(
        elevation: 5,
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
            Text(question),
            TextFormField(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter a value';
                }
              },
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This works great for a few fields, but when the list gets too long the values that are too far off the screen seem to get lost. When I click "Submit", The validation only goes up a little bit past the start of the current screen. I'm assuming this is an optimization for long lists, but how do I save my state and make the form validation check the whole list. I tried converting `SurveyQuestionView` to stateful and using [controllers](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) for the text fields, but that didn't help.

Do I just have to do all the form validation manually? or is there some way to get the built-in Form to handle this?

Alternatively, the list will never be that long. Is it possible to just turn off this optimization or use a different kind of scroll view?

Comment: Put the form fields in a column that is inside a single scroll view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put your widgets into a column the optimization should be turned off. But you can't directly scroll a column. Enter SingleChildScrollView. It's a widget that lets you scroll a single widget that will be its child.

So change this code:

```dart
Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: ListView(
        etc.
```

to

```dart
Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
              etc.
```

Comment: This does work, although the it still doesn't automatically scroll to the first error. It would be nice to be able to keep the performance benefits of an actual ListView while using a Form, but I guess that's not possible

Comment: I see. I believe I misunderstood your question. When you said "validation only goes up a little bit", I assumed you meant the actual validation functions for offscreen items wasn't working. However, if I understand correctly, the validations are working, but if something offscreen has an error during validation, it doesn't automatically scroll into view, right? I'll see if I can find a solution for that.

Comment: no you're correct. Before, the validation wasn't working at all for offscreen items, but it would automatically scroll to the first item that it did validate. With this solution, the actual validation is working but it just doesn't seem to automatically scroll at all, which is tolerable.